# Different results performing Part of Speech tagging using Core NLP and Stanford Parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

The Part Of Speech (POS) models that Stanford parser and Stanford CoreNlp
uses are different, that's why there is difference in the output of the POS tagging performed through Stanford Parser and CoreNlp.

- Online Core NLP Output

  - The/DT man/NN is/VBZ smoking/NN ./.
  - A/DT woman/NN rides/NNS a/DT horse/NN ./.
- Online Stanford Parser Output

  - The/DT man/NN is/VBZ smoking/VBG ./.
  - A/DT woman/NN rides/VBZ a/DT horse/NN ./.
    similarly more sentences

Is there documentation comparing two models and other detail explanation for the differences ?

It seems output of corenlp is wrong for these cases. Apart from few sentences which I checked during error analysis I guess there would be quite a lot of similar cases where these kind of errors might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really about CoreNLP, it's about whether you are using the Stanford POS tagger or the Stanford Parser (the PCFG parser) to do the POS tagging. (The PCFG parser usually does POS tagging as part of its parsing algorithm, although it can also use POS tags given from elsewhere.) Both sometimes make mistakes. On average, the POS tagger is a slightly better POS tagger than the parser. But, sometimes the parser wins, and in particular, it sometimes seems like it is better at tagging decisions that involve integrating clause-level information. At any rate, it gets these two examples right - though I bet you could also find some examples that go the other way.

If you want to use the PCFG parser for POS tagging in CoreNLP, simply omit the POS tagger, and move the parser earlier so that POS tags are available for the lemmatizer and regex-based NER:

```
java -mx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,parse,lemma,ner,dcoref -file test.txt
```

However, some of our other parsers (NN dependency parser, SR constituency parser) require POS tagging to have been done first.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and details..I tried using PCFG parser for POS tagging in CoreNLP and it works fine...

Comment: "On average, the POS tagger is slightly better POS tagger than the parser": how can we decide which one to use depending on our corpus ?  One possibility: if the parsing can be done properly for a sentence, if it's simple short sentence then it's better to use the parser as it will be able to look into the context and other information as you also mentioned "Parser is better at tagging decisions involve integrating clause-level information"